# Can I use Konva to draw an ellipse arc？

Tags: konvajs

Can konva draw an ellipse arc?
I want to draw an ellipse arc（`spanAngle = 180`）with two different radii such as 40 and 70.
Is there an API that I can use?
https://konvajs.org/docs/shapes/Arc.html in this demo i can only draw circle arc ，now i want to draw an ellipse arc（different radius are 40 and 70）

Comment: Can you attach a picture of your desired output?

Comment: https://konvajs.org/docs/shapes/Arc.html in this demo i can only draw circle arc ，now i want to draw an ellipse arc（different radius are 40 and 70）

Comment: I think you can use `scaleX` and `scaleY` to make an ellipse.